# Service class in android application for some task

Tags: android, service

My application uses some objects from a third party SDK which, on first call, take a long time to load.  What is a good way to avoid the long waiting period?

Is it possible to add a service class to my app which would do the object loading at device startup and then, when I launched my application, I wouldn't have the long waiting period since the objects would be already loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create a `Service` subclass and start it with `startService()`. Afterward, in your `Activity#onCreate()`, bind the activity to it and get the loaded object